# Is making tor to route through port 80 ,443 (standard internet ports ) is better for my anonymity

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is making tor to route through port 80 ,443 (standard internet ports ) is better for my anonymity so my ISP may watching default tor starting port ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 443 is an especially good port to use because traffic on that port is usually encrypted anyway. That is the port used for ssl or https, so when someone does Internet banking they use that port anyway. Because port 443 is used for encrypted traffic anyway most of the time, you using that port makes your usage seem more like normal Internet access.

Port 80 on the other hand is typically not encrypted when people use the internet. If you need to use 2 different ports because you want to run a bridge or relay, you might consider using port 443 and port 22. Port 22 is another one where almost all traffic is encrypted anyway because its used for a service called ssh.

So by using port 443 and 22, you would be keeping your Internet use looking pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

if you are digging around for this topic (as I was), might want to learn about tor bridges.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Avp2P_C5PMU
(not my video, just something useful)